# Bought a specimen copy of book

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

Some days ago my father bought a specimen copy of the book. Then one of my teachers said the book is for giving to the teachers for free and it is illegal to sell the specimen copy of books. Now, what can I do. Will it be permissible to read the book?